# Making a "clock" that prints out military time and adds/subtracts time

Tags: java, methods, time, tostring, clock

I'm trying to make a "clock" that does a few things:
1) Displays specified times as military time (00:00:00 for midnight)
2) Adds or subtracts a specified amount of time to the clock using the clock object, which has up to 3 integer parameters (h, m, s), and a math method or another clock object
-- Example)

```
System.out.print (c1 + " + 10 hours is ");
        c1.addHours(10);
        System.out.println (c1);
```

-- Example 2)

```
System.out.print (c4 + " + 12:59:55 is ");
            c4.addTime(12,59,55);
            System.out.println (c4);
```

So I'm having trouble with two things: the math methods and the toString() method that makes it all print out as it should. I'm new to the idea of toString() methods and they don't really make much sense yet. Here are the math and toString() methods I have, any help is appreciated.

```
//**********Methods to perform calculations w/ an object

    public void addHours(int h){
        if(this.hours + h > 23)
            hours = this.hours + (h % 24);
        else
            hours = this.hours + h;
    }

    public void addMinutes(int m){
        if(this.mins + m > 59){
            hours = this.hours + (m % 60);
            mins = this.mins + (hours % (m % 60));
        }
        else
            mins = this.mins + m;
    }

    public void addSeconds(int s){
        if(this.secs + s > 59){
            mins = this.mins + (s % 60);
            secs = this.secs + (mins % (s % 60));
        }
        else
            secs = this.secs + s;
    }

    public void addTime(int h, int m, int s){
        addHours(h);
        addMinutes(m);
        addSeconds(s);
    }


//Displays correctly formatted time
    public String toString(){
        if(hours > 23 || hours < 0)
            return "00:00:00";
        if(hours > 9)
            return "" + getHours();
        if(mins > 9)
            return "" + getMinutes();
        if(secs > 9)
            return "" + getSeconds();

        return "0" + getHours() + ":0" + getMinutes() + ":0" + getSeconds();
    }
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat; In Java 8, use the Time API otherwise use JodaTime

Comment: If you're not interested in using the preexisting APIs, I would maintain the time as the number of seconds since midnight, much easier to add/subtract values

Answer (score 0):

Your `add` methods are unnecessary complicated. You can simplify them. As in regards to `toSting()`: it seems to me, that you have a general misconception about `return`. A `return` statement ends the method. If your program comes across a `return`, the rest of the method's code is not executed. The statement following the return (if any) gets evaluated and returned.

```
public void addHours(int h) {
    // The "if" was semantically unnecessary
    this.hours += (h % 24);
}

public void addMinutes(int m) {
        // Forward to addHours, exploit integer arithmetics
        this.addHours(m / 60);
        this.mins += (m % 60);
}

public void addSeconds(int s) {
    // Forward to addMinutes, exploit integer arithmetics
    this.addMinutes(s / 60);
    this.secs += (s % 60);
}
[...]
//Displays correctly formatted time
public String toString() {
    if ((this.hours > 23)  || (this.hours < 0)) {
        return ("00:00:00");
    }
    String result = "";
    // Add a leading zero
    if (this.hours < 10) {
        result += "0";
    }
    result += (this.hours + ":");

    // Add a leading zero
    if (this.mins < 10) {
        result += "0";
    }
    builder.append(this.mins + ":");

    // Add a leading zero
    if (this.secs < 10) {
        result += "0";
    }
    builder.append(this.secs);

    return (result);
}
```

EDIT: In theory it would be possible to pass negative values to the `add` methods. If you want to be on the safe side, add some `if`-clauses to prevent time substraction.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up the math bit -- and I've added something I didn't show here that prevents unreal times from being possible. Unfortunately we haven't learned about StringBuilders yet and I don't think I should add it because... well, not only do I not know how to use it, but I also want to do it in a way that shows I understand the current material. But I'll look at what you've put and try to translate it to what I currently know.

Comment: @Mazzone make a `String` instead of a `StringBuilder` and "append" the Strings with `+`.

Comment: @Mazzone i edited the code to work with a `String` instead of a `StringBuilder`. Please take a look.